# Meteor.js Meteor-CollectionFS upload files using the method on the server side

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Hello and looking for any information on how to upload files using the method on the server side and whether it is possible.

This is my code:

file: client/template/new-wydarzenie.html
[file: new-wydarzenie.html](https://gist.github.com/samurai-jack/8377ed107677485fcb33)

file: client/template/new-wydarzenie.js
[file: new-wydarzenie.js](https://gist.github.com/samurai-jack/39ad57afd8258dbd327b)

server file: server/method/new-wydarzenie.js
[file: server method new-wydarzenie.js](https://gist.github.com/samurai-jack/a4f9b3a38ba8ccf6f859)

Comment: How would the file get to the method? Why not use CollectionFS's built-in stores and life-cycle hooks?

Comment: My knowledge is small. I have a server-side method that saves that "Article" in the database, for this article I would like to attach files. At this time, upload the files on the client side, and "article" on the server side. I do not know how to tie together the article and attached files

Comment: Doesn't the user create the article as well? Please share the relevant code.

Comment: Start by handling submission in one place. Your submission code is split between 2 handlers, which causes you to not be able to use the data from the CollectionFS and the other (article) collection in tandem.